# Lookalike audience: Total audience by country?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

How may I fetch the "total audience by country" for Lookalike audience creation, similar to Ads manager?

I've tried...

- geo location autocomplete, doesn't return audience size, like some targeting options do.
- reach estimate. For US (only) returns 182M. I guess I'm expected somewhere near 250M

...or am I off here in my assumption that 25M is 10% of total audience in US?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello Garrett, did you managed to create your tool? I'm currently trying to do exactly the same thing, we are trying to create a simpler tool like audience insight, but couldn't find any API.

Answer (score -1):

In most cases , the use of look a like is created from a custom audience , and with it the lookalike generated will have more relevance.

researching the api facebook ads, found this:

When optimized for similarity, a lookalike audience will include the top 1% of people in the selected country who are most similar to the seed Custom Audience. The reach of the new audience will be smaller, but the match will be more precise.

When optimized for reach, a lookalike audience will include the top 5% of people in the selected country that are similar to the seed Custom Audience, but with a less precise match.

Instead of using types you can manually set a ratio value that represents the top x% of the audience in the selected country. The ratio value should be between 1%-20% and should be specified in intervals of 1%.

Comment: yeah I know all that, my problem is mimicking the FB power editor, which displays the slider representing 1-10% by "total audience by country" as you can see from the screenshot. We don't want a slider from 1-10(or 20)%, as it doesn't represent the potential reach of the audience, and would confuse end users.

But thanks for trying